# Symfony and Java Applet The routing?

Tags: java, symfony, applet, classnotfoundexception

I would like to be able to run a Java applet from a web page.

Here is my page Myapplet.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
  <object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
    <param name="code" value="test" >
    <param name="archive" value="{{ asset('bundles/tvm/Java/test.jar') }}" >
  </object>
{% endblock %}
```

My applet is just a test just to test the routing.
This applet works fine in "Run as Applet" in Eclipse.

```
public class TVM extends JApplet {

    public void init() 
     { 
       final JButton b = new JButton( "File" ); 
       b.addActionListener(  
         new ActionListener() 
         { 
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) 
           { 
             JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
             fc.setCurrentDirectory( new File( "C:\\" ) ); 
             int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog( TVM.this );  
             String fileName = "C:\\image.jpeg" ; 
             if ( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )    
             {   
               File aFile = fc.getSelectedFile();   
               fileName = aFile.getName();   
             } 
             System.out.println( fileName ); 

           } 
         }); 
         getContentPane().add( b ); 
     } 
}
```

I always have an error

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

Test.jar my file is located in \Symfony\web\bundles\tvm\Java and Symfony \src\Personal\TVMBundle\Resources\public\Java

I really tried many things but alas to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess the exception is thrown in your applet? If so, did you import the required namespaces, .e.g. `java.io.*` for `File`?

Comment: My applet work fine and here is my list of import

`import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
`import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

Comment: So in other words the ClassNotFoundException is from PHP/Symfony? If so,  I don't think the template-snippet you provided is the problem. Does it say which file was not found and can you maybe provide an error message and stack trace?

Comment: Yes this is it.
And no ... when I click on the the java error message there is nothing  in the console.

Comment: Is this applet available at an URL we can visit it?  Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: As an aside, after the `ClassNotFoundException` is solved, you can look forward to `AccessControlException`..